# Why does compilation take longer in Play 2.3.4 (activator) vs Play 2.2.4 (play)?

Tags: java, scala, playframework-2.0, sbt, typesafe-activator

**Scenario 1:**

Start Play **2.2.4** project with command `play ~run`, then move some code from A.java to B.java => the following output:

`[info] Compiling 2 Java sources to D:\MyProject\target\scala-2.10\classes...
[info] Compiling 1 Java source to D:\MyProject\target\scala-2.10\classes...
[warn] Note: D:\MyProject\app\controllers\AdminController.java uses or overrides a deprec
ated API.
[warn] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
[success] Compiled in 4s`

**Scenario 2:**

Start Play **2.3.4** (activator) project with command `activator ~run`, then move some code from A.java to B.java => the following output:

`[info] Compiling 9 Scala sources and 368 Java sources to D:\MyProject\target\scala-2.11\c
lasses...
[warn] Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
[warn] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
[success] Compiled in 64s`

Why does Play 2.3.4 recompile all the sources in the second case? Is there a setting for that? Both scenarios are for the same project and in both cases I ran `play/activator clean` and `play/activator compile` before making the change.

Comment: I think you'll have to give people the actual projects and then someone who knows the incremental compiler could look at what happens in them. This is sbt in both cases ; play and activator here are irrelevant (to this scenario) wrapper scripts around sbt. I think you may have different versions of sbt here though, maybe 0.13.2 and 0.13.4 or something, not sure exactly.

Comment: Indeed, Play 2.2.4 uses sbt 0.13.0, while Play 2.3.4 uses 0.13.5. It's probably an issue with the new sbt version. Or maybe I'm missing some setting somewhere.

Comment: if you put sbt.version=0.13.5 in project/build.properties for the 2.2 project it ought to force upgrade 2.2 and you could see if that matters